# How to add an automatic restart after the game has ended into my tic tac toe program?

Tags: python

so I've recently started learning how to program using Python and I tried to create a tic tac toe game with minimal video help to test my general knowledge, except I kind of hit a roadblock...I have everything set, but I am trying to add some code that will restart the program from scratch after the game has ended (victory or tie). How would I go about doing this?

Here is my current code. Feel free to make some other suggestions as they would really help a beginner out like me.

```
board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]


def playing_board():
    print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2])
    print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5])
    print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8])



def game_time():
    position = "X"
    count = 0
    while True:
        playing_board()
        selection = int(input(position + ", choose your position 1-9: ")) - 1
        if (board[selection]) == "-":
            board[selection] = position
            count += 1
            if count == 9:
                print("Tie!")
        else:
            print("Sorry that position is already taken. Choose again")
            continue
        if board[0] == board[1] == board[2] == position or \
            board[0] == board[4] == board[8] == position or \
            board[3] == board[4] == board[5] == position or \
            board[6] == board[7] == board[8] == position or \
            board[6] == board[4] == board[2] == position or \
            board[0] == board[3] == board[6] == position or \
            board[1] == board[4] == board[7] == position or \
            board[2] == board[5] == board[8] == position:
            playing_board()
            print(position + " wins!")
        if position == "X":
            position = "O"
        else:
            position = "X"
        

def new_game():

    while True:
        user_input = input("Would you like to play another game? (Y/N): ")
        if user_input.upper() == "Y":
            continue
        elif user_input.upper() == "N":
            print("Okay, cya!")
            quit()
        else:
            print("I didn't quit get that...")



game_time()
```

Comment: Why not move `game_time()` after `if user_input.upper() == "Y":`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
while True:
    board = ['-', '-', '-',
             '-', '-', '-',
             '-', '-', '-']
    game_time()
```

However, this does not put into effect the `new_game()` function you created. To use that, you need to change the `continue` to `game_time()` and use

```
new_game()
```

at the end.

**Some other suggestions:**

1. The function `playing_board_2()` is not used and is the same as `playing_board()`. You can remove that.
2. The function `win_check()` is not used. You can remove that.
3. The variables `count` and `position` are defined globally **and** in `game_time()`. Because they are not used globally, you can just remove the global definitions and leave the definitions in `game_time()`.
4. After `print`ing `"Tie!"`/`"X wins!"` in `game_time()`, you **need** to add a `return` statement to quit the function, or the `while True` will never end.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it! And yeah I totally forgot to remove the functions that I wasn't using when I first copied and pasted the code into here as I was originally trying to make use of them to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The global `board` variable is quite a obstacle. You have multiple options:

1. Learn about classes and then make the `board` variable a instance variable and convert most of the functions to member functions. Then create a new Game object every time the user starts a new game. This is the cleaner way, but you will need to learn some things.
2. Wrap the `game_time()` function inside a `while True:` and reset the board every time. This is the easiest fix, but it's not a very clean one.

Answer (score 0):

I repaired main idea of your code. Check if wins? in `while` loop:

```
board = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]


def playing_board():
    print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2])
    print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5])
    print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8])


def win_check(pos):
    if board[0] == board[1] == board[2] == pos or \
        board[0] == board[4] == board[8] == pos or \
        board[3] == board[4] == board[5] == pos or \
        board[6] == board[7] == board[8] == pos or \
        board[6] == board[4] == board[2] == pos or \
        board[0] == board[3] == board[6] == pos or \
        board[1] == board[4] == board[7] == pos or \
        board[2] == board[5] == board[8] == pos:
            return True
    else :
        return False


count = 0
position = "X"
def game_time():
    position = "X"
    count = 0
    while True:
        playing_board()
        if position == 'X' and count != 0:
            if win_check('O'):
                print('O', 'wins')
                break       
        elif position == 'O' and count != 0:
            if win_check('X'):
                print('X', 'wins')
                break
        selection = int(input(position + ", choose your position 1-9: ")) - 1
        if (board[selection]) == "-":
            board[selection] = position
            count += 1
            if count == 9:
                print("Tie!")
        else:
            print("Sorry that position is already taken. Choose again")
        if position == "X":
            position = "O"
        else:
            position = "X"


game_time()
```